# Problem with POST request from swift frontend

Tags: ios, json, swift, flask

I'm trying to implement the Swift front end so that it can upload data onto the database, which is written in Python via Flask and utilizes PostgreSQL. My frontend Swift code for sending a POST request is currently as follow, and is written within a View Controller if that matters:

```swift
func PostData(){

        let parameters:[String: Any]=["latitude":  35.0094040,
                        "longitude": -85.3275640,
                        "tag": "this is my fancy tag",
                        "image":"icecream.jpg"]
        let jsonURLString="http://localhost/api/tags"
        guard let url=URL(string: jsonURLString) else{
            return
        }
        var request=URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod="POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody=try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])  else{
            return
        }
        request.httpBody=httpBody
        let session=URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, error) in


            if let data=data{
                do{
                    try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])  
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

My backend code for accepting post request is as follow:

```py
@app.route('/api/tags',  methods=  ["GET",  "POST"])
def get_tags_api():
    if request.method == "POST":
        latitude  =  request.form.get("latitude")
        longitude  =  request.form.get("longitude")
        text  =  request.form.get("tag")
        image_  =  request.form.get("image", None)
        print (latitude)
        print (longitude)
        print (text) 
        print (image_)
        create_tags(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude, text=text, image=image_)
```

When I tried to run the following code, I ended up with the following error message from Xcode:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

On the backend, all the variables were printed as None, with the following error message:

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO tags (text, longitude, latitude, image) VALUES (%(text)s, %(longitude)s, %(latitude)s, %(image)s) RETURNING tags.id]
[parameters: {'text': None, 'longitude': None, 'latitude': None, 'image': None}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Given that the backend displayed an error message when the front end PostData function is run, the request must have been sent, but the backend isn't detecting any data from the request, which I don't know why that is.  I'm not sure what I've done wrong here.  I'm rather new to Swift, and I don't have that much experience with Flask. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong.

```
guard let httpBody=try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])  else {
     return
}
```

You can refer to [Alamofire - ParameterEncoding.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift)

Comment: I'm not using Alamofire, so I'm not sure if the reference is relevant

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encoding data before request to server. You can try this code:

```
guard let jsonData=try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])  else {return}
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of jsonString?  I already have guard let httpBody=try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])  else{return}.  I'm not sure where I am supposed to put the line you wrote in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
let parameters:[String: Any] = ["latitude":  35.0094040,
                                "longitude": -85.3275640,
                                "tag": "this is my fancy tag",
                                "image":"icecream.jpg"]

private func query(_ parameters: [String: Any]) -> String {
    var components: [(String, String)] = []
    for key in parameters.keys.sorted(by: <) {
        let value = parameters[key]!
        components.append((escape(key), escape("\(value)")))
    }
    return components.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&")
}

public func escape(_ string: String) -> String {
      let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@"
      let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="
      var allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
      allowedCharacterSet.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")
      var escaped = ""
      if #available(iOS 8.3, *) {
         escaped = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) ?? string
      } else {
         let batchSize = 50
         var index = string.startIndex
         while index != string.endIndex {
               let startIndex = index
               let endIndex = string.index(index, offsetBy: batchSize, limitedBy: string.endIndex) ?? string.endIndex
               let range = startIndex..<endIndex
               let substring = string[range]
               escaped += substring.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) ?? String(substring)
               index = endIndex
         }
      }      
    return escaped
}
request.httpBody = query(parameters).data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but it is best to add some text explaining what the problem is and why this fixes it - i.e. the confusion between sending JSON and expecting form post data in the Python code.

Comment: I tried the code.  Didn't work.   Returned the same error